# How to comma separate an array of integers in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have a list of integers, i want to convert them into comma separated integers, how can i actually achieve that

The result should have comma separated integers, not comma separated string
example

```
def evaluate(self, list_of_integers):
   print(list_of_integers) # [220.0, 112.9] 
   # i want to achieve something like below
   print(comma_separated_integers) # 220.0, 112.9
```

Comment: Try: `comma_separated_integers = ','.join(map(str, list_of_integers))`

Comment: if you want to be more pythonic, could even do a generator expression instead of `map` like so:  `",".join((str(i) for i in list_of_integers))`

Comment: no, it should be a integer, when i do this, it converts the comma separated value as string

Comment: Well - _printing_ needs strings anyway - it is just the **output** that is converted - not your list itself if you do `print(','.join(map(str, list_of_integers))) `

Answer (score 4):

You can convert them to strings and then use `str.join`:

```
integers = [106, 386, 53]

', '.join(map(str, integers))
```

Output:

```
'106, 386, 53'
```

Comment: no, it should be a integer, when i do this, it converts the comma separated value as string

Comment: The concept of "comma separated integers" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have `list` of numbers:

```
numbers = [220.0, 112.9]
```

and you just want to print:

```
220.0, 112.9
```

you could do:

```
print(*numbers,sep=', ') # prints 220.0, 112.9
```

Star-operator (also known as unpack operator) means that element of list which follows will be used as subsequent arguments. `sep=', '` means that printed element will be separated by `,` followed by space.