# How to extract data using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am extracting a string line to put it into csv with precise columns. The data looks like this:

> Andrew Taggart 12345678 Math: 90 English: 78 Physics: 85

> Jame Bond 1012478 English: 97 Physics: 85 Chemistry: 76

> Hope Williams 1478978 Math: 89 English: 85 Physics: 76

and I want the output look like this

> Name, Student_ID, Math, English, Physics, Chemistry

> Andrew Taggart, 12345678, 90, 78, 85, -1

> Jame Bond, 1012478, -1, 97, 85, 76

> Hope Williams, 1478978, 89, 85, 76, -1

the format will be:

> name|subject1|subject2|subject3

> name1|23|34|23

> name2|3|2|5

Note that after each columns there will be specified by "," and if student don't have grade on that subject it will be (-1) - like it is for Chemistry.

Here is my code so far.

```
import re
student = "Andrew Taggart 12345678 Math: 90 English: 78 Physics: 85"
        
name = re.split (r'(\d+)', student) [0] #extract name 
-> Output: Andrew Taggart
ID = re.split (r'(\d+)', student) [1] #extract ID 
-> Output: 12345678 

headers = ["Math", "English", "Physics", "Chemistry"] 
grade = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", student) [1:] 
-> Output: ["90", "78", "85"]
student_grade = list (i.strip().replace(":", "") for i in re.split (r"(\d+.\d+|\d+')", student)) [2:-1] 
-> Output: ["Math", "90", "English", "78", "Physics", "85"]
```

Comment: I don't really understand your problem, if you are already able to extract all the data then just merge it in one list and then separate the elements in the list with commas? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044301/how-to-comma-separate-an-array-of-integers-in-python)

Comment: no, i want to extract the data with to its precise columns with the student's grade for that subject. My problem here is I don't know how to put it into each subject. And for the subject that student doesn't take an exam, I can't set it into (-1)

Comment: can you provide with an example of a subject with -1

Comment: Andrew Taggart 12345678 Math: 90 English: 78 Physics: 85

Comment: so for this example, the student doesn't take exam in Chemistry so the value will return to (-1) as in the output. 

(Name, Student_ID, Math, English, Physics, Chemistry)

(Andrew Taggart, 12345678, 90, 78, 85, -1)
the value for Chemistry is set to (-1)

Answer (score 1):

This does not return it the way you want, but may help.

```
formatted = {}
for word in data.split():
    try:
        num = int(word)
        formatted.update({key: num})
        key=""
    except ValueError as ex:
        if key == "":
            key = word
        else: 
            key += f" {word}"
```

And the output is such as:

```
{'Andrew Taggart': 12345678, 'Math:': 90, 'English:': 78, 'Physics:': 85}
```

You can easily use this format to create a csv.

----EDIT------

```
result = []
 data = """Andrew Taggart 12345678 Math: 90 English: 78 Physics: 85
 Jame Bond 1012478 English: 97 Physics: 85 Chemistry: 76
 Hope Williams 1478978 Math: 89 English: 85 Physics: 76"""
 for line in data.split("\n"):
     student = True
     form = {}
     for word in line.split():
         try:
             num = int(word)
             if student:
                 form.update({"name": key, "student_id": num})
                 student, key = False, ""
                 continue
             form.update({key: num})
             key=""        
         except ValueError as ex:
             if key == "":
                 key = word
                 continue
             key += f" {word}"
     result.append(form)
```

Then just do:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(result).fillna(-1)
```

And you get:

```
             name  student_id  Math:  English:  Physics:  Chemistry:
0  Andrew Taggart    12345678   90.0        78        85        -1.0
1       Jame Bond     1012478   -1.0        97        85        76.0
2   Hope Williams     1478978   89.0        85        76        -1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I was also thinking of converting it into dictionary type. But I think your way can avoid mistake.

Comment: You probably want to put the subjects as columns and the name of the student as first element of the row, right? so It looks something like this:
name|subject1|subject2|subject3
name1|23|34|23
name2|3|2|5

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want!

Comment: Can you assume that student name and ID will always be the first elements on your data source?

Comment: yes, it is always in the first in the data source.

Comment: Alright, give me a sec and I will update the proposed solution.
Can you just update the data source to contain more examples?

Comment: yes, please check more examples in question.

Comment: @ViệtThắng check if you like it :)

You get it in pandas, so just use the metohd to_csv.